# Error: module 'rustworkx' has no attribute 'visit' when trying to execute a quantum circuit in a real quantum computer from IBM

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience

I am trying to use a real quantum computer from IBM. I have the next code:

```
qc = QuantumCircuit(2,2)
qc.h(0)
qc.cx(0, 1)
qc.ry(np.pi/2, 0)
qc.measure(1,0)

IBMQ.save_account('MY TOKEN')
IBMQ.load_account()
provider = IBMQ.get_provider(hub='ibm-q', group='open', project='main')
backend = provider.get_backend('ibm_nairobi')
mapped_circuit = transpile(qc, backend=backend)
qobj = assemble(mapped_circuit, backend=backend, shots=1024)
job = backend.run(qobj)
result = job.result()
counts = result.get_counts()
print(counts)
```

Instead of "MY TOKEN" I have wrote my token and that's not the problem. The problem is when my circuit try to execute in the real quantum computer that I get the error **module 'rustworkx' has no attribute 'visit'** in Python